# Group Theory - Permutations

Tags: permutations

If $B \in S_7$ and $|B^3| = 7$, prove that $|B|=7$.

Solution: As $o(B^k) = o(B) / (o(B),k) $
Thus $|B| / (|B|,3) = 7$
Let $|B| = 7a$. Then
$7a/(7a,3)$ should be $7a/a = 7$ or $(7a,3) = a$.

As $3$ is a prime number and can only be factored into $3$ and $1$. So $a = 3$ or $a=1$.
So $a = 3$ or $a = 2$.

So $|B|$ $=$ $7$ or $21$.

My question is how to remove the possibility of $B = 21$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the known facts special to symmetric groups. Any element is a product of disjoint cycles; and the least  common multiple of the lengths of these cycles is the order of that element. Now work backwards and see what it would mean for $B\in S_7$ to be of order 21.